# SQL: Can I refer/access data the current row in a window function?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Here is an example. Suppose I have the following table:

```
 id     | list
--------+----------
 10     |
        | 10,20
 20     | 10,20
```

For each `id` value, I'd like to calculate the number of rows having a `list` value which contains that `id` value. The result would be look like that:

```
 id     | count of lists
--------+----------
 10     | 2
        | 0
 20     | 2
```

I suggest a window function should be used, but it seems that I can't access the `id` value from within such a function.

I totally agree that it is **BAD** design. This question is about the possibility.

Any MySQL/PostgreSQL solution is fine.

Comment: No clue what you are trying to ask.  ID 10 has a blank, but blank has 0 counts?  blank ID is a bit weird as well.  Is their an upper limit to values in list?  The design is horrid here

Comment: This just looks like really bad table design... for both columns...  Why do you have the values you're looking for as a separate column in the table that contains the list values?  Why are you storing comma-separated values in the database to begin with?  Think about what would happen if you had `100` in the list, and you were looking for `10`.  This would require an overly complex solution to something that could be easily done had the design be thought through.

Comment: Mysql or postgres??

Comment: Please tag properly.  Mysql or postgres?  Can't be both.

Comment: looks to me you want to count the number off the comma separated list?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using MySQL, and assuming that your table has the name `test`, and assuming that both columns are string types:

```
SELECT
  t1.id, count(t2.list)
FROM
(test t1 LEFT JOIN test t2 ON
  (t2.list LIKE CONCAT('%,', t1.id, ',%')) OR
  (t2.list LIKE CONCAT('%,', t1.id)) OR
  (t2.list LIKE CONCAT(t1.id, ',%')))
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

Please be aware that this solution might be very slow depending on the number of records you have and depending on the average length of the strings in the `list` field.

If you need something faster, I think it couldn't be a single query. Perhaps we would have to write a stored procedure or some application logic for that, or use additional tables or columns and a series of multiple SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

Before I start, as mentioned above, this is a poor design. However, this is how I would query it:

```
CREATE TABLE #Lists (id int, list varchar(500));
INSERT INTO #Lists (id, list) VALUES
    (10, NULL), (NULL, '10,20'), (20, '10,20');

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT LEFT(list, INSTR(list, '%,%')-1) AS value, SUBSTRING(list, INSTR(list, '%,%') + 1, 500) AS list FROM #Lists
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CASE WHEN list LIKE ('%,%') THEN LEFT(list, INSTR(list, '%,%')-1) ELSE list END AS value, CASE WHEN list LIKE ('%,%') THEN SUBSTRING(list, INSTR(list, '%,%') + 1, 500) END AS list FROM cte 
    WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(list) > 0
)

SELECT value, COUNT(*) FROM cte GROUP BY value;

DROP TABLE #Lists;
```

This solution allows for any number of values in the `list` string (like '10,20,30').

Ideally, the list values should be stored in a separate table so that each record has a single value, such as `CREATE TABLE BetterDesign (id int, value int) INSERT INTO BetterDesign (id, value) VALUES (10, NULL), (NULL, 10), (NULL, 20), (20, 10), (20, 20)`. Along with a million other reasons, this is better for querying `SELECT value, COUNT(*) FROM BetterDesign GROUP BY value`. That being said, I understand the pains of legacy systems.