# PostgreSQL Window Function: How to reference a column from the current row vs. a column from the frame row?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

[[db<>fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=92b20a3ffe6a748f546d3839711379bb)]

I have the following data, by `group`, each row having an increasing `index`, and containing a `limit` and a `value`:

```
CREATE TABLE items ("group" VARCHAR, index INTEGER, "limit" INTEGER, value INTEGER) ;

INSERT INTO items ("group", index, "limit", value) VALUES 
  ('A', 1, 2, 1), ('A', 2, NULL, 3), 
  ('B', 1, 3, 2), ('B', 2, NULL, 2), ('B', 3, 1, 3), ('B', 4, 2, 5), 
  ('C', 1, 2, 3), ('C', 2, 2, 3), ('C', 3, NULL, 4), ('C', 4, 5, 5) ;
```

```
 group | index | limit | value 
-------+-------+-------+-------
 A     |     1 |     2 |     1
 A     |     2 |       |     3
 B     |     1 |     3 |     2
 B     |     2 |       |     2
 B     |     3 |     1 |     3
 B     |     4 |     2 |     5
 C     |     1 |     2 |     3
 C     |     2 |     2 |     3
 C     |     3 |       |     4
 C     |     4 |     5 |     5
```

For each row, I want to know the `next` `index` from the same `group` whose `value` is stricly above the `limit` of the current row, i.e.:

```
 group | index | limit | value | next
-------+-------+-------+-------+------
 A     |     1 |     2 |     1 |    2
 A     |     2 |       |     3 |     
 B     |     1 |     3 |     2 |    4
 B     |     2 |       |     2 |    
 B     |     3 |     1 |     3 |    4
 B     |     4 |     2 |     5 |    
 C     |     1 |     2 |     3 |    4
 C     |     2 |     2 |     1 |    4
 C     |     3 |       |     1 |    
 C     |     4 |     5 |     5 |
```

**Question**: how to achieve this with window functions? I thought about the following query, but I do not know how to specify in my `CASE` that `limit` refers to the current row while `value` refers to the frame row:

```
SELECT *,
       MIN(CASE WHEN value < "limit" THEN index ELSE NULL END) 
              OVER (PARTITION by "group" ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS next
FROM items
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: [More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694386/sql-can-i-refer-access-data-the-current-row-in-a-window-function) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396434/referencing-current-row-in-filter-clause-of-window-function) along these lines. So the answer seems to be that current row values cannot be referenced.